# Very basic question on continuous representations

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a topological group, i.e. 
$$G \times G \to G, (g,h) \mapsto gh ~~~~ G \to G, g \mapsto g^{-1}$$
are continuous. Suppose $K$ is a field with norm $|\cdot|$ on it and $V$ is a normed vector space over $K$. Then, the continuous, linear maps from $V$ to $V$ can be endowed with the norm topology. Let $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ be a group homomorphism (i.e. a representation). I wonder whether the following are equivalent:

(a$_0$) For each $v \in V$ fixed, $g \mapsto \rho(g)v$ is continuous

(a) $G \times V \to V, (g,v) \mapsto \rho(g)v$ is continuous

(b) $G \to GL(V), g \mapsto \rho(g)$ is continuous

(c) For every $v \in V$ fixed, the map $g \mapsto \rho(g)v$ is continuous at $g=1_G$ (the neutral element) and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ around $1_G$ such that for every pair $g, h \in G$, $g^{-1}h \in U$ implies $|||\rho(g^{-1}h)||| < \epsilon$ where $|||\cdot|||$ is the operator norm.

This much I know/suspect:

The implication (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a) is straightforward, and (c) $\Rightarrow$ (b) one can find in Knapp, Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups. Now the question is:

**does (a) imply (c)?**

Obviously, (a) implies that $g \mapsto \rho(g)v$ is completely continuous for all $v \in V$.

On $a_0$: I am pretty sure that it is not equivalent. Tried though I have, I was unable to construct a counterexample. This might be the reason: It is equivalent to (a) if $G$ is either finite or compact and $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$: Then one can endow $V$ with a scalar product such that the rep. becomes unitary, i.e. $(\rho(g)v, \rho(g)w) = (v,w)$. From this one can deduce ($a_0$) $\Rightarrow$ (a). So here, the question is:

**Can someone provide a counter example s.t. ($a_0$) is satisfied but (a) is not?**

best wishes,

Fabian Werner

Comment: Using the triangle inequality, $(a_0)$ implies $(a)$ without assuming compactness if in addition $\sup_{g \in G} |||\rho(g)||| \lt \infty$ holds. // The norm topology on $GL(V)$ is too strong in general, usually one uses the strong operator topology. See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66394/) for more on this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. Maybe the question should stick to finite dimensional vector spaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(a) does not imply (c):** The second condition in (c) may be written in the following equivalent and simpler way:

$$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists U\in\mathcal{N}_1 \quad \forall g\in U \quad |||\rho(g)|||<\epsilon.$$

(Here $\mathcal{N}_1$ denotes the collection of all neighborhoods of $1$ in $G$.) However, one cannot expect above to hold true since in any case $U$ will contain $1$ and $|||\rho(1)|||=|||\mathrm{id}_V|||=1.$

**For almost all cases of interest, (a$_0$) and (a) are equivalent:** If $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group and $V$ a Banach space, then (a$_0$) and (a) are indeed equivalent (see Corollary 2-2 on p. 49 of the book *Fourier Analysis on Number Fields* by Ramakrishnan and Valenza). This means that if there really is an example of the sort you ask, it should be quite unusual.

Comment: Oh ok... that is surprising. Thanks!!

Comment: Let me add that there is an error in the statement of the aforementioned Corollary 2-2: the codomain of $\rho$ should be $\mathrm{Aut_{top}}(V)$ rather than $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$. It is this corrected version of Corollary 2-2 that we use in the equivalence of (a$_0$) and (a).